# Can I use JDBC and R2DBC alongside each other in the same Spring application?

Tags: spring, jdbc, r2dbc

I have been working on a spring application for some time now and it has been using JDBC to retrieve data from my Postgres database server.

Now my application has progressed to the point that it requires some reactive system to it. In my case, I am trying to emit user interaction (mainly notifications) as a stream to my REST service and this requires a non-blocking functionality that is not provided by JDBC but by R2DBC.

My question is, is it possible to use both R2DBC and JDBC together in the same application? I only need to stream notifications and the rest is perfectly fine using JDBC.

Comment: Why do you think you wouldn't be able to use both in a single application? Did you try it and did it fail? To be clear: using both R2DBC and JDBC in a single application should work just fine.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I was able to set it up last night and make it function but I was afraid combining the non-blocking system with blocking system could compromise the reactive nature of R2DBC functionality as I read it somewhere if I am not mistaken. However, since I am not combining the two codes together, I hope it will be fine. Otherwise, a whole year of work will have to go to trash because my app desperately needs a reactive functionality at its core.

Comment: Performing blocking calls like JDBC inside reactive code is not advisable, no. But there is no problem using both in a single application itself, as long as they aren't mixed together in some way, as you will need to guard against accidentally calling code that blocks (eg by calling JDBC) from your reactive code.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to use both JDBC and R2DBC in a single application. There is nothing in either specification that prevents this, and it is unlikely that there is anything in an implementation of either specification that would interfere with an implementation of the other specification.

That said, performing blocking calls like JDBC inside reactive code is not advisable. But there is no problem using both in a single application itself, as long as they aren't mixed together in some way, as you will need to guard against accidentally calling code that blocks (eg by calling JDBC) from your reactive code.